# Partitioning an external HDD using GPT and with a "Microsoft Reserved" partition?

Tags: partition, grub2, gparted, gpt

I've just bought a 4TB external HDD, and need some advice before partitioning it.  Usually I just delete everything and partition (and create filesystems) from scratch, but this time I *really* needed to store some stuff, so I'll have to re-size (with `gparted`) instead...

The HDD uses GPT boot-label.  Apart from one 3.7TB NTFS-partition, it also got a small "Microsoft Reserved"-partition (which I don't know quite what to do with... mostly because I don't know what it's for).

From `cfdisk`:

```
                                 Disk: /dev/sdd
             Size: 3,7 TiB, 4000787025920 bytes, 7814037160 sectors
          Label: gpt, identifier: 9669F8EF-29AA-4A5C-8AE3-FD452B079B46

Device          Start          End      Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1          34       262177       262144   128M Microsoft reserved   
/dev/sdd2      264192   7814035455   7813771264   3,7T Microsoft basic data
```

I will mostly be using the drive with Linux, but I may occasionally use it with Windows too.

I plan to shrink the current large NTFS-partition to free-up most of the drive.  I'll also plan to add a small FAT-partition.  The rest will be used for *several* EXT4-partition.

I'd also like to make the drive bootable - and install GRUB - so I can (optionally) install some distros on some of the EXT4-partition (I'd like the option).

Problem is that I'm not very familiar with **GPT**.  I've usually used the old-style DOS/MBR label, but can't this time since I've already started to use the drive.

I saw some tips in the *Gentto* handbook:

```
Partition       Filesystem      Size    Description
/dev/sda1       (bootloader)    2M      BIOS boot partition
/dev/sda2       ext2 (or vfat)  128M    Boot partition
/dev/sda3       (swap)          512M+   Swap partition
/dev/sda4       ext4            Rest    Root partition
```

and:

```
(parted)print

Model: Virtio Block Device (virtblk)
Disk /dev/sda: 20480MiB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number   Start      End      Size     File system  Name   Flags
 1       1.00MiB    3.00MiB  2.00MiB               grub   bios_grub
 2       3.00MiB    131MiB   128MiB                boot   boot
 3       131MiB     643MiB   512MiB                swap
 4       643MiB     20479MiB 19836MiB              rootfs
```

I guess I can drop #2 (/dev/sda2), since that is the *boot-partition* and I'll rather take my chances with just a *root-partition* instead.

I'll obviously need to create a *grub-partition* so I can install the bootloader.

But what about my external HDD's *current* 1st partition (/dev/sdd1) - the "Microsoft reserved" partition?  Do I need it (remember, I may want to use the drive for Windows too)?  May there be something interesting on it already (from the drive manufacture) I should keep/save?  Or can I just delete it?

If I must keep the "Microsoft reserved" partition, must it be the first partition on the drive - or can it be the 2nd?  What about the *grub-partition* - must it be the 1st partition on the drive, or can it be anywhere (ie. *after* "MS reserved") as long as the correct flags are set?

So what I'd like to end-up with, are something like the following:

```
/dev/sdd1  GRUB  (bootloader)
/dev/sdd2  Microsoft Reserved  (unless I can just delete it)
/dev/sdd3  NTFS  (shrunk down by a lot - 200-500GB)
/dev/sdd4  FAT   (small - just 50-200GB)
/dev/sdd5  EXT4  (200-500GB)
/dev/sdd.. Several more EXT4 partitions...
...
...
```

So to repeat my questions:

1) Does the "Microsoft Reserved" partition serve a purpose, what is it, and do I need it (or can I just remove it)?

2) If I do need it (or even if I don't), must it be first on the HDD - or can it be 2nd (after the boot-loader)?

3) Must the GRUB-partition (boot-loader) be the first partition on the drive, or can it be anywhere if I set the correct flags?  (At worst, it'll be 2nd, after "MS reserved".)

4) Are there any other exceptionally unwise things I've proposed doing?

Answer (score 4):

- A [Microsoft Reserved Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition), or MSR, is a partition of a data storage device, which is created simply to reserve a chunk of disk space for possible subsequent use by the operating system software of a Windows operating system. No data is stored within the MSR; Windows may take from the MSR partition for the creation of new partitions, which themselves may contain data structures. (Wikipedia)
- You need it only if you plan to use the disk as a Windows system disk. It is not needed on a Windows data disk.
- The GRUB partition does not need to be the first one.
- If you plan to boot from this disk under UEFI you need an [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition), formatted FAT32 (`vfat` in Linux terminology). This is in addition from any `/boot` partition.

Comment: Could I move/recreate the MS Reserved partition, or must it be first on the disk?  Could I for example put it after the NTFS-partition (eg. GRUB, NTFS, MSRes, Ext4, Ext4, ...)

Comment: @BaardKopperud: Yes. The question is why do you need _one_ NTFS partition? If this disk will be used Windows as a _data_ disk then you do not needs a MSR partition at all; if this disk will be used to boot Windows then you should really let the Windows installer do its thing.

Comment: if the HDD is only to be used for Ubuntu then can this MSR thing be removed? (I have another HDD solely dedicated for Windows)

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: Linux (including Ubuntu) does not use it in any way. Only Windows uses it (as a reserve of disk space), but only on a system disk.

Comment: @AlexP - Why would an external hard drive allocated a Microsoft Reserved Partition? What do you mean by "system disk" and "data disk"?  What do you mean by "subsequent use by the operating system software of a Windows operating system"?

Comment: @Motivated: A *system* disk is a disk from which the system boots. A *data* disk is any disk which is not a system disk. An external drive may or may not have a "Microsoft Reserved" partition; it's usually not needed. By subsequent use I mean some use in the future; Windows uses the "Microsoft Reserved" partition as a sort of reserve from where it takes small chunks of space when it needs to create a small partition for its own purposes.

Comment: @AlexP - Thanks. Do you mean that a system disk is the partition that holds the bootloader? I take it that data disk is a partition to store files other than those required by the operating system  or is a hybrid? For example, would it be files such as program files, application specific files and/or personal files e.g. Microsoft Word documents?

Comment: @AlexP - Why would an external drive have a system partition? I would not expect an external drive to boot.

Comment: @AlexP - Why would it have the label "Microsoft Reserved" as opposed to NTFS/exFAT/HPFS?

Comment: @Motivated: It's not a label, it's a partition type, identified by GUID E3C9E316-0B5C-4DB8-817D-F92DF00215AE. It does not contain a filesystem (NTFS or whatever); in fact it does not contain any data at all, unless by accident.

Comment: @AlexP - Apologies AlexP. It is confusing. If it a partition type, why is not considered to be a filesystem? Additionally, if it isn't a filesystem how can it be considered to be a system drive (assuming my preceding understanding is correct)?

Comment: @Motivated: A partition is a contiguous number of blocks on a disk. It may contain a filesystem, it may contain some other kind of data structure (for example, a chunk of an Oracle database, or a LVM physical disk), or it may not contain any data at all. A partition type is metadata associated with the partition itself, and does not have any necessary relationship with the contents of the partition. And finally, the *disk* is a system disk; in particular, on Windows, the system disk is the disk with the partition containing the NTFS filesystem with the directory %SYSTEMROOT%.

Comment: @Thanks AlexP. That's clear. I would have thought that for any data structure to exist, the partition must have a filesystem. Is it still considered to be a system disk if it does not have the directory %SYSTEMROOT%?

Comment: @Motivated: By definition, Windows considers the system disk to be the disk which contains %SYSTEMROOT% (which is usually C:\Windows). (Actually, it's more complicated, but it's good enough for an introduction.) Enter `set system` at a command prompt to see the current values of %SYSTEMDRIVE% and %SYSTEMROOT%.